# Where to look Mathematics.SE statistics?

Tags: support, stackexchange, statistics

Where can I see statistics on the number of questions per day, percentage of answered, number of users etc?

I guess there should a common mechanism across stackexchange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#science-questions

[image]

Comment: The default, I think, maybe grid view. One may have to click on the top right of the page to switch to list view to show the output given in the answer.

Comment: @WillieWong I edited the link, I forgot that the list view isn't the default as the page remembers my selection.

Comment: Sweet: I changed the link a little bit so now Mathematics comes first. `:-)`

Comment: For the comparison - similar statistics from the time when the site change from beta can be found at [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3355/mathematics).